# Summing columns in access reports based on other column's text

Tags: ms-access

so I'm using Microsoft access reports and I need to be able to sum only the rows in a column that are designated in a separate column by text.  So column A has either a Y or N for every row and I need to sum the numbers in column B that have a Y in column A.

I just don't know how to designate which numbers should be summed using the other column.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried something that is not working? What is your error message?

Comment: It's telling me I have syntax errors but that's just because I don't know how to write the expression. 

It's currently written like this:
=Sum([B])/([B Grand Total Sum])

with B representing the column with the numbers and I need it to only sum the B values that have a Y in column A.

Answer (score 0):

`Sum(Iif([A]="Y",[B],0))/SUM([B])` Should do the trick.

This will add `B` if `A = Y` and `0` if `A <> Y`, then divide that `SUM` by The overall total of Column B.

You could also do this in the underlying query...

Answer (score 0):

```
IIF(A='Y',Sum([B]/[B Grand Total Sum]), 0)
```

Wouldn't you want to evaluate the A criteria before you SUM anything up?

Honestly in this case I don't think it matters, but in general you will want to do evaluations of criteria before you do any aggregations or you're inevitably decreasing your performance. Also, your results may be inaccurate if you do IIF evaluations of columns outside of the summation.

Comment: That's why the summation belongs inside the if. If A=y add B, if not add 0 for that row. Your answer ignores the OP's parentheses.